# Cannot access the value in the JS Object

Tags: javascript

REALLY annoying problem I encountered today. I just cannot read the values of an object via the right key.

Here is the the debugging screen around the object:

[image]

I evaluated the `message` object in the chrome - *Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)*

[image]

But as you can see that the

`console.log(message.line)`

and

`console.log(message.content)`

output **undefined**.

Whaaat is really going on?

Thank you, guys!

### Update

I solved this issue by `rename` the `message` from antd. But I am still wondering why this could happen since the `message` should be overwritten by the innermost `message`. Can anyone try to explain? Thank you!

Comment: Put your `JSON` data into your question, so that I can help, you may replace data values with dummy data, keeping keys same.

Comment: I just found out that I am using 'message' from 'antd' in the js file which caused this. https://ant.design/components/message/ I changed to `import { message as Message } from 'antd';` and solved the problem, thank you.